# How to change the border color when error Helper text appears on TextField?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I am using React Material UI `TextField` element. The thing I want is when I press submit button the helpertext which I get is "Please enter the password".

**Like this:**

[image]

But when the helpertext appears I need to change the `TextField` border color to the color which I want to apply from the SCSS file. As I want to change the border color through the SCSS file.

The thing I want is on focus is something like this. The `TextField` border should be red and its outline should be blue:

[image]

The code I have done so far:

```
<TextField
  id="form-el-2 outlined-basic"
  name="userName"
  variant="outlined"
  placeholder={"Please enter valid password"}
  helperText={
    errorMsgs.userNameErr && errorMsgs.userNameErr.length
      ? errorMsgs.userNameErr
      : null
  }
  onChange={handleChange}
  value={cabinetInfo.userName}
/>;
```

And also SCSS:

```
.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #c4c4c4;
    outline: 1px solid $primary-color !important;
    outline-offset: 1px;
  }
```

How to do that? Is this possible? Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class, then apply it to your component conditionaly

```
// Whatever classname or styles you want
.text-field-with-error {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #c4c4c4;
    outline: 1px solid $primary-color !important;
    outline-offset: 1px;
}
```

and the Jsx part will be:

```
<TextField className={hasError ? "text-field-with-error" : " "} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `error` prop to the `<TextField />`

Refer this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/0ppb3?file=/demo.js:502-682) or Material-ui [documentation](https://mui.com/api/text-field/) here.

```html
<TextField
  error
  id="outlined-error-helper-text"
  label="Error"
  defaultValue="Hello World"
  helperText="Incorrect entry."
/>
```

Comment: Ok thanks. your error props worked. I have one issue that do you see the border top blue line which is below the Password label? That line has more gap then left, right and bottom offset. Do you know how to fix this to make top offset same as the left, right or bottom??